# Angular 2 application changes not getting reflected after deployment on IIS

Tags: angular, iis, browser, deployment

I have deployed an angular 2 application on IIS by creating virtual directory. It is running succesfully. When I make any changes in my application(Either html file, or compnonents) changes are not getting reflected when I am browsing application from iis. 
When I am trying to run the same application using angular CLI, then changes are geting reflected and visible in browser.

Things I have checked already.

1. Path in IIS is correct.
2. Have tried to build project again.

Comment: Have you checked your cache settings?

Comment: Thanks @DeborahK. I am following your pluralsight courses to learn angular2. Yes, I have cleared all of that. even tried to open the application in incognito window.

Comment: just a thought, I assume you are rebuilding/re-bundling you CLI project and then deploying to IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Been awhile.. and no answers?  i had the same problem but running in Azure app service not IIS; using Chrome.  i even stopped the service and it still renders old version? What??... must be caching...

Yup..clearing cache fixed.
click settings |  Clear browsing data
-> Checked 'cookies and other site data' and press 'clear data'

if that doesn't work(missing something on your clearing of cache) try another browser that you've never run the app in.

Update:  i narrowed it down as nobody likes to kill all settings. notice you're on 'Basic' settings.  click under 'advanced settings'.  only check 'Cached Images and files' and then click 'clear data'.